# keyboard shortcut to switch between amazon workspace and local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I use windows 10. I just started to use Amazon Workspace for work, and I have to use a virtual windows 10 inside aws. Is there any keyboard  shortcut to switch from the virtual desktop to my local windows. I know I could do this with the mouse, by simply clicking outside the workspace, but I cannot do this, as I am blind and I use a screen reader.
Basically on MS remote desktop client, you can just press control plus alt plus end to give the local machine keyboard focus, is there anyway to do something like this on AWS. I have also noticed that when inside AWS, the virtual machine doesn’t have full keyboard access as in some of the shortcut that I might use are picked up by my local machine rather than AWS. This doesn’t happen in MS remote desktop client. So is there any keyboard  shortcut to switch between local machine and AWS and also give AWS full keyboard access so that when inside AWS, my local machine doesn’t pick up shortcuts that I might use inside AWS?

Answer (score 2):

I got here because I had a similar problem to find no answers.
A short search yielded the following thread in an amazon [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=159825).

To summarize, the feature was requested in 2014 but I am not sure if it was answered, however, these are a few helpful tips:

- You can toggle full screen mode using ctrl+alt+enter
- When in full screen mode you can move the mouse to one of the upper corners and then move to the right or left for the Workspace menu bar to appear, click on it (no need to select any menu) and use alt+tab and will switch between your local machine apps.

Hope this helped you, if you find anything please do share it with me as I am still searching the topic.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Alt-Tab switches between apps on the current desktop, as it should.